# Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timestamp

If you have DB columns `created_at` and `updated_at` Rails will automatically set those values when you create and update a model object. Is there a way to save the model without touching those columns?

I am bringing in some legacy data and I would like to set those values from the corresponding values in the (differently named) legacy data fields. I'm finding when I set them on the model and then save the model, Rails appears to override the incoming values.

Of course I could just name the Rails model columns differently to prevent that, but after the data is imported, I want Rails to do its automatic timestamp thing.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Do this in a migration or in a rake task (or in [the new database seeds](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4932f7b38f72104819022abca0c952ba6f9888cb) if you're on edge rails):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
begin
  run_the_code_that_imports_the_data
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = true  # don't forget to enable it again!
end
```

You can safely set `created_at` and `updated_at` manually, Rails won't complain.

Note: 
    This also works on individual models, e.g. 
     `User.record_timestamps = false`

Comment: You can even pull this into a method, e.g.
`def without_timestamps
    old = ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps
    ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = old
    end
  end`

Comment: Do we need to reset it back to `true` even when executing scrips or code inside the console ?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/37193298/1214748 is much better. It doesn't turn it off globally for the whole application

Comment: @maschwenk true, for rails 5. but for those forced to use an older version of rails, this still seems the best option.

Comment: In no way shape or form, I would imagine :) Migrations runs before the app starts though, iirc, so it shouldn't matter. (It's been a while since I've done rails, so correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 59):

use update_column method instead:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column

```
update_column(name, value)
# Updates a single attribute of an object, without calling save.
```

Validation is skipped.

Callbacks are skipped.

updated_at/updated_on column is not updated if that column is available.

Raises an ActiveRecordError when called on new objects, or when the name attribute is marked as readonly.

Comment: Mind that for serialized columns you will have to yaml the value yourself beforehand.

Answer (score 45):

Rails 5 provides a convenient way to update a record without updating it's timestamp `updated_at`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save

You, just need to pass `touch:false` while updating your record.

```
>> user = User.first
>> user.updated_at
=> Thu, 28 Apr 2016 20:01:57 IST +05:30
>> user.name = "Jose"
>> user.save(touch: false)
=> true

>> user.updated_at
=> Thu, 28 Apr 2016 20:01:57 IST +05:30
```

Comment: This by far is the cleanest way to move the records.

Comment: Seems a little odd that the same option doesn't work when doing `update`. You need to split it into two operations as shown here.

Answer (score 30):

You can set the following inside your migration:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
```

Or altenatively use update_all:

> **update_all(updates, conditions = nil, options = {})**
>
> Updates all records with details given
>   if they match a set of conditions
>   supplied, limits and order can also be
>   supplied. This method constructs a
>   single SQL UPDATE statement and sends
>   it straight to the database. It does
>   not instantiate the involved models
>   and it does not trigger Active Record
>   callbacks.

Answer (score 16):

In Rails 3+, for a single object, set `record_timestamps` for the object rather than class. I.e.,

```
>> user = User.first
>> user.updated_at
=> Tue, 12 Apr 2016 22:47:51 GMT +00:00
>> user.name = "Jose"
=> "Jose"
>> user.record_timestamps = false
>> user.save
=> true
>> user.updated_at
=> Tue, 12 Apr 2016 22:47:51 GMT +00:00
>> User.record_timestamps
=> true
```

This way, you don't touch global state for the model, and you don't have to remember to restore the prior setting in an `ensure` block.

Comment: This is the most clean method to do this when you do a single update prior to Rails 5.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to other answers, I found to my surprise that disabling timestamps for a single model, like in:

```
User.record_timestamps = false
```

worked for my development database, but not on my pre-production database, which runs on a different server. However it works if I disable timestamps for all models with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
```

(Situation: modifying the created_at attribute in a migration)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a one-time import, you could do the following:

1. Create model using `legacy_created_at` and `legacy_updated_at` fields.
2. Load legacy data.  Map into the model fields as desired.  You can use `#save` and generally not worry about using `update_all` or the like, and you can use callbacks if desired.
3. Create a migration to rename the columns to `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use a mixin module to temporarily turn off time-stamping in a block:

```
module WithoutTimestamps
  def without_timestamps
    old = ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps
    ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = old
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use it wherever you need it

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WithoutTimestamps

  def save_without_timestamps
    without_timestamps do
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

Or just a one-off like this:

```
m = MyModel.find(1)
WithoutTimestamps.without_timestamps do
  m.save!
end
```

Comment: Just a warning, this is not threadsafe. Recently got bitten by this!

Answer (score 2):

When not in a bulk import, you can override the should_record_timestamps? method on your model to add new checks on when to update the updated_at column.

Answer (score 1):

Or, for thread safety, see: http://www.hungryfools.com/2007/07/turning-off-activerecord-timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make `ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps` flag change anything, and the only working way is using `ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching {}`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching do
  Project.first.touch  # does nothing
  Message.first.touch  # does nothing
end

Project.no_touching do
  Project.first.touch  # does nothing
  Message.first.touch  # works, but does not touch the associated project
end
```

Taken from [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoTouching/ClassMethods.html).

This is very useful for rake tasks where you have to override some properties of deeply-related models and don't want to bother about inner callbacks, while your users rely on `created_at` or `updated_at` attributes or those are used as sorting columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but this is how we skip updating `updated_at` in my shop:

```rb
# config/initializers/no_timestamping.rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    def update_record_without_timestamping
      class << self
        def record_timestamps; false; end
      end

      save!

      class << self
        remove_method :record_timestamps
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
post.something = 'whatever'
post.update_record_without_timestamping
```