# How to update a single attribute without touching the updated_at attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I achieve this?

tried to create 2 methods, called

```
def disable_timestamps
  ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
end

def enable_timestamps
  ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = true
end
```

and the update method itself:

```
def increment_pagehit
  update_attribute(:pagehit, pagehit+1)
end
```

turn timestamps on and off using callbacks like:

```
before_update :disable_timestamps, :only => :increment_pagehit
after_update :enable_timestamps, :only => :increment_pagehit
```

but it's not updating anything, even the desired attribute (pagehit).

Any advice? I don't want to have to create another table just to count the pagehits.

Comment: Try using `update_attributes!(:pagehit => pagehit+1)` and see if you get any errors. BTW, did you paste the `def disable_timestamps` twice by mistake here, or is it the same in your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

Or closer to your question:

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/01/21/override-automatic-timestamp-in-activerecord-rails.html

Answer (score 104):

As an alternative to `update_attribute`, In Rails 3.1+ you can use `update_column`.

`update_attribute` skips validations, but will touch `updated_at` and execute callbacks.

`update_column` skips validations, does not touch `updated_at`, and does not execute callbacks.

Thus, `update_column` is a great choice if you don't want to affect `updated_at` and don't need callbacks.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html for more information.

Also note that `update_column` will update the value of the attribute in the in-memory model and it won't be marked as dirty.  For example:

```
p = Person.new(:name => "Nathan")
p.save
p.update_column(:name, "Andrew")
p.name == "Andrew" # True
p.name_changed? # False
```

Comment: The Mongoid equivalent of `update_column` is `set`, as in `person.set(:name, 'Andrew')`. [Mongoid Docs - Atomic Persistence](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#atomic)

Answer (score 13):

If all you're wanting to do is increment a counter, I'd use the `increment_counter` method instead:

```
ModelName.increment_counter :pagehit, id
```

Comment: I want to increment the counter but without change the updated_at value.

Comment: This works, and there is a new way in Rails 3. One thing I notice is that the counter is incremented after the page view.

Comment: @lulalala you must reload the object to if you want to reflect the new count. example: `object.reload`

Answer (score 3):

it is not a good idea to do this:

```
self.class.update_all({ pagehit: pagehit+1 }, { id: id })
```

it should be

```
self.class.update_all("pagehit = pagehit + 1", { id: id })
```

the reason is if two requests are parallel, on the first version both will update the pagehits with the same number, as it uses the number saved in the Ruby memory. The second option uses the sql server to increase the number by 1, in case two of these queries come at the same time, the server will process them one after the other, and will end up with the correct number of pagehits.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid Monkeypatchingtroubles you could also use ModelName.update_all for this purpose:

```
def increment_pagehit
  self.class.update_all({ pagehit: pagehit+1 }, { id: id })
end
```

This also does not touch the timestamps on the record.

Answer (score 2):

You also have [`decrement`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/decrement) and [`increment`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment) (and their bang versions) which do not alter `updated_at`, do not go trigger validation callbacks and are obviously handy for counters / integers.

Answer (score 0):

If precision is not really that important, and you don't expect the code to run many times, you can try altering the saved in the database `updated_at` value, like so:

```
u = User.first
u.name = "Alex 2" # make some changes...
u.updated_at = u.updated_at + 0.000001.second # alter updated_at
u.save
```

so that Rails will actually try to save the same value, and not replace it with `Time.now`.