# Update Rails model without touching timestamp temporary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `Tweet` model. I want to update the model attributes but without updating the timestamp.

I've already read/tried some links and didn't work for me:

- [How to update a single attribute without touch updated_at attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887668/how-to-update-a-single-attribute-without-touch-updated-at-attribute)
- http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/01/21/override-automatic-timestamp-in-activerecord-rails.html

I tried to override `ActiveRecord::Base` as mentioned in the second link, by creating a new file `active_record_base_patches.rb` inside `lib` directory. But, the engine said that the method was not found in `Tweet` model.

So, I tried to move the `update_record_without_timestamping` to `Tweet` model. The method is found now but the timestamp is updated.

Is there any simple method to disable timestamp in Rails for a while? 
Laravel 4 has something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906324/3427434.

PS: I use Ruby on Rails 4.2.3 on Ruby 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create concern in `model/concern`, named it with `model_timestamp.rb`

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module ModelTimestamp
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def without_timestamps
      old = ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps
      ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
      begin 
        yield 
      ensure
        ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = old
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model `Tweet` add `include ModelTimestamp`

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelTimestamp

  ...
end
```

Then where you want to update your attributes without `timestamps` to change use

```
tweet = Tweet.last
Tweet.without_timestamps do
  tweet.update(attributes)
end
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it didn't work. I noticed a trigger: `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in a column.
After I removed the trigger, I tried your solution once more, and it is working now.