# Update attribute without altering the updated_at field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timestamp

I'm running rails 3.0. I have a object I want to change a boolean field on but do not want to change the updated_at timestamp. We won't be upgrading rails any time soon, so update_column is out of the question. I'd rather not make model-level changes to support this (like in this post: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/01/21/override-automatic-timestamp-in-activerecord-rails.html), since many of objects of this type may have methods called on them at the same time.

Comment: You can always run some raw SQL, can't you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use .update_all:

```
User.where(:id => @user.id).update_all(:your_bool_field => true)
```

Comment: Beware this doesn't trigger callbacks

Answer (score 9):

You can set record_timestamps attribute as false before updating.

```
User.record_timestamps=false
User.first.update_attributes(:field1 => "Test")
User.record_timestamps=true
```

For more:
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/01/21/override-automatic-timestamp-in-activerecord-rails.html

Comment: right, I posted a link to that blog post in my original question. I'm looking for other ways to do it, that don't involve change the class properties.

Comment: This is very dangerous, while your update_attributes is being run any user updated will not be timestamped. For a single user that is not a problem for concurrent users that can easily break.

Answer (score 9):

Rails 5 allows updating a record without updating timestamps.

In Rails 4.x, when we save an ActiveRecord object then Rails automatically updates fields `updated_at` or `updated_on`

Addition of touch option in `ActiveRecord::Base#save`.

In Rails 5, by passing `touch: false` as an option to save, we can update the object without updating timestamps. The default option for `touch` is `true`.

```
>> user = User.new(name: 'David', email: 'david@example.com')
>> user.save
   INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at", "email") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) 
   [["name", "John"], ["created_at", 2016-05-12 05:10:22 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-05-12 05:10:22 UTC], ["email", "john@example.com"]]
=> true

>> user.updated_at
=> Thu, 12 May 2016 05:10:22 UTC +00:00
>> user.name = "John"
>> user.save(touch: false)
  UPDATE "users" SET "name" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["name", "John"], ["id", 12]]
=> true

>> user.updated_at
=> Thu, 12 May 2016 05:10:22 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: This is likely people's best option here. As the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) explain, there are callbacks that trigger when `save` is called on any ActiveModel instance. Alternative solutions in this thread, such as `update_all`, will [skip those callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations), which may often be undesirable.