# Rails association touch always edit updated_at although something is not changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have serious problem with touch directive in Rails association.

It always edit updated_at timestamp. That is weird because when associated object is not changed, always update timestamp.

Have Place

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one     :location,        inverse_of: :place, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :location_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

and Location

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place, inverse_of: :location, touch: true

  attr_accessible :number, :street, :locality, :region, :postal_code, :country, :description, :description_en, :latitude, :longitude
  attr_accessible :place_id

  validates :place,       presence: true
  validates :number,      presence: true
  validates :street,      presence: true
  validates :locality,    presence: true
  validates :postal_code, presence: true, postal_code: { country: :sk }
  validates :latitude,    presence: true, numericality: true, allow_nil: true
  validates :longitude,   presence: true, numericality: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

When i load and save existed place without changes:

```
Place.last.save # changed? == false
```

it automaticaly edit updated_at

```
SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `places` SET `updated_at` = '2012-11-18 20:38:48' WHERE `places`.`id` = 490
```

Do someone any experience with this how to fix it or something?

Uses Rails 3.2.9 and MySQL (mysql2 adapter)

EDIT:

Location.last.save changed to Place.last.save. It was mistake.

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields

Comment: Not so much related. I want automatic update, but with right behaviour.

Comment: Indeed - sorry about that.  However, I can reproduce this behaviour using `Location.last.save` but not `Place.last.save` on Rails 3.2.8.  In both cases, it follows the documentation correctly where `:touch => :true` touches the timestamp on an associated object during update.

Comment: Maybe i have some weird gem, or something. Must more test it and isolate problem. Because it start this on existing projekt.

Comment: ADD: Your are right that Location.last.save updates, but for me Place.last.save do ti too.

Comment: OK. I isolate this, it doing only when is `has_one` association. If is `has_many` it works as i excepted.

Answer (score 1):

The rails `touch` directive is likely modeled loosely after the established and expected behavior of the Unix tool of the same name.

According to the documentation it isn't broken.

If it isn't doing what you want it to do, it is likely the wrong approach.

---

From the [documentation at RailsAPI](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/):

> ### **touch(name = nil)**
>
> Saves the record with the updated_at/on attributes set to the current
>   time. Please note     that no validation is performed and no callbacks
>   are executed. If an attribute name is passed,     that attribute is
>   updated along with updated_at/on attributes.

The man description for touch on Linux:

> ### **TOUCH(1)**
>
> Description
>   Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.

---

If you really think it is the wrong behavior, you are free to submit a patch or report a bug.

Comment: See, when is parent object saved (@place.save) and associated object should be saved within. But when they doesn't has any changes, are not saved. So they doesnt touch to parent main object (updated_at is not edited) But i get behavior that is changed at this is problem. I have more than 5 models nested to parent, and from SQL log i can see, that updated_at is changes as so much as are models.