# How to call update_column for several records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I do something like this?

```
Item.where(id: [2, 5, 8]).update_column(calendar_id: 5)
```

Obviously this gives an error, but is there a similar method?

I just don't want callbacks to get triggered, or timestamps to get changed.
And calling a loop seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all):

```
Item.where(id: [2, 5, 8]).update_all(calendar_id: 5)
```

Comment: It works. I was only worried because I've seen somewhere it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run `update_attribute` on each `Item` after disabling timestamps in ActiveRecord.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields) for how to disable timestamps.