# Update object, while retaining the update_at timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I want to update an attribute on an object, but keep the attribute `updated_at` (DateTime type) unchanged.

This doesn't seem to work, the `updated_at` gets current date/time:

```
p = Post.first
p.update(updated_at: p.updated_at, published: true)
```

Comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/01/21/override-automatic-timestamp-in-activerecord-rails.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked and answered here: [Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

But the short answer is to use `update_columns` . `i.e. user.update_columns(last_request_at: Time.current)`

More info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column

Answer (score 1):

Just use update_all method, it does not touch updated_at field
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Comment: disadvantage of this method is it’s not invoke validation of model.

Comment: Yep, but OP simply changes published flag.
In more complex cases it is better to avoid such method.