# update a column without changing updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This may sound like an odd request, however, I have am using impressionist, and using a cached hit column.  I am also updating another column everytime it gets a hit, which is a separate calculation.

I don't want to update updated_at at this time, is there a way to skip that?

```
if impressionist(@topic, "message...", :unique => [:session_hash])
  @topic.increment(:exp, 1).save
end
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [update_columns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns) method from `ActiveRecord::Persistence` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to do this while using `increment` method? or do i just have to do a manual increment (+1)?

Comment: thank you, I got it with : `@topic.update_columns(exp:@topic.increment(:exp, 1).exp)`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to disabling timestamps for an entire class (which isn't thread safe), you can disable timestamps for an individual instance:

```
@topic.record_timestamps = false
@topic.increment(:exp, 1).save
```

This instance will not create or update timestamps until timestamps are re-enabled for it. This only affects this particular instance, other instances (even if they refer to the same row in the database) are not affected.

Comment: i get an undefined method

Comment: `@topic.record_timestamps = false`

`@topic.increment(:exp, 1).save`

Answer (score 4):

Just disable `record_timestamps` before `increment`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false

@topic.increment(:exp, 1).save

ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = true
```

[Is there a way to avoid automatically updating Rails timestamp fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861448/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-automatically-updating-rails-timestamp-fields)

Thread-safe version: [update dataset without updating magic timestamp columns](http://ck.kennt-wayne.de/2013/oct/rails-update-dataset-without-updating-magic-timestamp-columns)

Comment: Doesn't look thread-safe, but maybe AR is using thread locals internally?

Comment: It changes a global attribute on `ActiveRecord::Base`, so it will affect all threads that are running, not just the current one.

Comment: here is a thread-safe version: http://ck.kennt-wayne.de/2013/oct/rails-update-dataset-without-updating-magic-timestamp-columns

Comment: Ha! Nice find. Seems like something that will probably break from some future Rails update, though.

Comment: @ShalevShalit You should consider the possibility that the code being executed may raise an error, so you should use an ensure block (as per the link in your answer).

Answer (score 3):

Since Rails 5, you can pass the `touch` argument to the save method in order to avoid updating the updated_at column:

```
user.name = "New Name"
user.save(touch: false) # doesn't update updated_at
```